# Translate strings in order mail

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-community, locale

After using a lot of time trying to translate Magento strings using translate.csv without any luck, I am now using a plugin called PHPro Translate.

In this, I can search for all strings in my shop and translate them one by one.

However, I can't seem to translate the strings used in e-mail templates. In my items.phtml, I have `$this->__('Item in your order')` and `$this->__('Items in your order')` that show up in english, even though my shop is in danish language.

Can someone please help me sort this out so I can translate the strings and get them to show up correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** After some discussion in the comments below this answer it appeared that there were some custom text strings in the file
>
> ```
> app/design/frontend/rwd/{theme}/template/email/order/items.phtml
> ```
>
> The issue was solved by adding translations for those strings in
>
> ```
> app/locale/da_DK/Mage_Sales.csv
> ```

Original answer below this line

---

Email template files are located in `app/locale/yourlanguage_YOURLANGUAGE/template/email/`

In your case, all Danish email translation files should be in

```
app/locale/da_DK/template/email/
```

If there are no Danish email files in this location then you should copy all email templates from `app/locale/en_US/template/email/` to the Danish directory and translate them.

I'm sure Danish email templates can be found on the web.

Comment: Thanks. I have localized that file, and made the correct changes in it. Problem is that it collects list of items in the order from the file 'items.phtml'. In which folder would I place a danish version of this?

Comment: Can you post the entire path to the `items.phtml` file which your installation is using? By default Magento CE 1.9.2.1 is using `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items.phtml` and the string is `<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Items Ordered')) ?>`. Notice the difference? **"Items Ordered"** is translated in `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv` by default.

Comment: The file is in the folder you mention - in my case /app/design/frontend/rwd/{theme}/template/email/order. I guess the guy who originally set up the store has altered some things along the way. Maybe he made this change to support both Item and itemS ordered. Can I just implement both strings with your code? `<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Item Ordered')) ?>` and `<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Items Ordered')) ?>`

Comment: Based on your original question I would suggest adding both `"Item in your order","Singular Danish translation"` and `"Items in your order","Plural Danish translation"` to your `app/locale/da_DK/Mage_Sales.csv` file. Also don't forget to refresh all cache. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thx. But isn't it bad practice to make changes in this core file?

Comment: Magento by default only contains translation files for the `app/locale/en_US/` directory. For that reason files in `app/locale/da_DK/` can't be referred to as core files. The change won't be overwritten when you upgrade. It's basically just adding some Danish translation. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great, I have updated my answer with this solution. Please mark it as accepted.